# React-router-dom's Link messes up styles for material-ui's AppBar Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-router, material-ui

As explained [here](https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/#third-party-routing-library), you can easily use a `material-ui` `Button` in combination with `react-router-dom`'s `Link` like so:

```js
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

<Button component={Link} to="/open-collective">
  Link
</Button>
```

However, this way, in any scenario where you try to use `color="inherit"` (which seems to be the default solution for `Button` in [AppBar](https://material-ui.com/demos/app-bar/)) the default `a:hover` stylings will override the button's own theme settings because `Link` renders an anchor element (`<a>`), specifically:

1. Text appears blue when hovering over them, in most browsers.
2. The click ripple animation does not show while hovering.

I guess the `AppBar` examples always use `color="inherit"`, making it hard for an MUI beginner like myself to find a solution here. How do I use `color` and `palette` without `inherit` and still work in `AppBar`? Setting `color="primary"` makes it have the same color as the `AppBar`, making it invisible, while `color="secondary"` results in an unusable red tint.

What can I do to get my pretty buttons back if I cannot use `inherit`?

Comment: I use buttons in this manner frequently without any of the style issues you mentioned. In [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/r5zzlw3zyq) I do not see any visual difference in styling between the regular buttons and the ones using `Link`. If you see something different, please indicate what browser you are using. If you have different code that shows the behavior you describe, please share a sandbox that reproduces it.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thank you for your comprehensive reply! I found my issue: I used `color="inherit"`! Setting it to a pre-configured color name fixes it :)

Comment: @RyanCogswell I updated my question correspondingly. The problem is that the `AppBar` examples always use `color="inherit"`, and I have not yet found a way to get a proper button with `component="Link"` in `AppBar` as a result. Would largely appreciate any working basic solution! :)

Comment: [Here is a modified AppBar example](https://codesandbox.io/s/k5oxkxjxv3) using `Link` and I still don't see any of the styling issues you mentioned. Please share a sandbox that reproduces what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks @RyanCogswell for all the help! Thanks to you, I finally found the culprit, and posted an answer! :D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @RyanCogswell, I was made aware of the fact that this very likely not a problem with MUI per se. Instead, I found out that it is a fight between MUI and Bootstrap (I'm sure it's not recommended to mix the two, however Bootstrap offers some cool stuff that MUI doesn't have and vice versa).

After some more debugging, I found that Bootstrap overrides some global tag styles, including `a:hover` [right here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/19aee321a027edaa60c3087bfcf6c9f1517c9b98/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L161).

I fixed it by overriding those settings like so:

```css
a[role="button"]:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Glad you found the culprit, but this solution is likely to cause you additional pain if you are using Link Buttons outside of the AppBar and want a color other than `inherit`. Is "!important" necessary? Having "[role='button']" should already make this rule more specific than the Bootstrap rule, so I would expect it to win without "!important".

Comment: @RyanCogswell You were right! `!important` was not necessary! Thank you once more! :)